# Sleep mode on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: suspend

There was such an idea to put the computer into sleep mode using keyboard shortcuts.

I found the `pm-suspend` command and it puts the computer into sleep mode, but when the computer is turning on, it does not require entering a password to login.

So the question is:  **How to make a sleep mode with the help of the terminal and to require a password to enter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install xdotool if not yet installed by `sudo apt install xdotool`
2. Create a script with below content

Content of the script named `pm.sh` in my home folder..

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo pm-suspend
xdg-screensaver lock
xdotool sleep 1 key Return
```

3. make the script executable `chmod +x /home/user/pm.sh`
4. Run the script `/home/user/pm.sh`

See this short video. when the screen blanks, I just pressed power button and screen presented with entering password. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU4fo.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ubuntu-lock-on-suspend key in dconf.  If you do this, the screen will be locked after resume from suspend, such as shutting the lid on your laptop.  It will also lock when resul=ming from sleep mode, triggered by suspend and hibernate.

In a command line, use the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

**--or--**

Graphically, open `dconf` and navigate to /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver, and set the value for ubuntu-lock-on-suspend to True.  Similarly, set /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown disable-lock-screen to False
[image]

Comment: did not working

Comment: @nosferatu-id Check the value of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen` - this should be "False", and I edited the answer to reflect this.